# Create my own MapBox Vector tile and self hosting

Tags: postgis, mapbox, mbtiles, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I understood hosting mbtiles is possible and some solutions are available. I not sure that I can find the answer; 
How can I create my own vector tiles (mapbox vector tile format) which from my data stored in postgis or geojson etc.

Should I download mbtiles from mapbox?

Comment: Note that mbtiles is different from vector tiles! Which one is of interest to you?!

Answer (score 6):

As stated by other people, mbtiles were just raster format stored in a sqlite database using a particular specification.

Nowadays, it's seems that it's reuse to store vector tiles using the same scheme.

For vector tiles generation to mapbox vector tile format, you have choices listed at https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles#servers

You can also look at the recent [osm2vectortiles project](http://osm2vectortiles.org) to directly download vector tiles stored in mbtiles. You can serve them following [this recipe](http://osm2vectortiles.org/docs/serve-vector-tiles/).